# Java How to Write Spesific String to Txt File Line By Line(Tesseract Output)

Tags: java, file, tesseract

I need to print my result string line by line to TXT file.
Here is my code:

```
        try {

        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\testfiles\\enes.txt");
        try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer)){
                //printWriter.write(result);
                printWriter.println(result);
}
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getCause());
    }
```

Also my console output is like this:

İbrahim Enes ALAN

Küçükbakkalköy, 2. Hazine Sk., 34750 Ataşehir/İstanbul Efo Academic Aparts
Tel. No: (542)6299228

E-mail: en@ozu.edu.tr / en@hotmail.c0m

As you can see my console output printed line by line which is I want.But in my txt file all words in one line.How can I print like my console output. 
Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `printWriter.write("\r\n");` or `printWriter.write(System.lineSeparator())` depends on your operation system

```
try {

    String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\testfiles\\enes.txt");
    try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer)){
    printWriter.write(result);
    printWriter.write("\r\n");
}
   System.out.println(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getCause());
}
```

Comment: Actually I try both ways and they didnt work but thanks to you I find a proper solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by Tesseract already has lines delimited by EOL characters `\n`. On Windows, they would appear as one line. You'd need to replace it with Windows EOL characters `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.After quick reseach with EOL characters I fixed the problem.